# How to configure JNDI datasource for database conection pooling in Google App Engine

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, jndi, apache-commons-dbcp

My simple Google App Engine based web app needs to connect to a PostgreSQL database that has been developed and deployed on the Amazon RDS.

My questions are:

- Can I use JNDI datasource in a GAE web app and how to connect to an
  external database?
- Which database connection pool library should I use for it, Tomcat
  DBCP or Apache Jakarta Connection Pool?
- Is there any best practice for how-to configure it in a GAE web app?